# How can I print a list of all the Git repos in my home directory with all of their branches?

Tags: macos, git

I misplaced a file somewhere in a branch of one of the many repos I have on my system. I'm not even sure what repo it was, but I think I'll recognize the branch name if I see it.

Is there a way to print out a list of all of my repos and each of the branches they contain?

Answer (score 1):

This command will do the trick:

```
find ~ -type d -name ".git" -print -exec git --git-dir={} branch \;
```

This searches inside your home directory for every directory named `.git`. For each matching directory, it prints the directory name and then runs `git branch` to list its branches, passing the directory name to that command.

Since we are searching for the `.git` subdirectory and not the repo root directly, the directory name printed and passed to `git branch` includes the `.git` subdirectory at the end. I thought it might be necessary to remove this from the directory name, but `git branch` works fine with it, so this simple command is good enough.

Comment: Maybe take out the `-type d`, submodules hoist the `.git` dir out of the way and replace it with a `.git` file containing `gitdir: path/to/real/repo`.  You can do the same with `git init --separate-work-dir=path/to/real/repo`.